# codeigniter php Event management system.. I want to make notification when the event is created

Tags: php, codeigniter, notifications

Good Day sir. can someone help me i'm trying to code for notification. Event management system. The admin will create the event for scholars. During the process the creation of the event the admin will choose what scholarship is the event for. When the admin finish creating the event this scholars from this scholarship will automatically receive their notification. My problem is i can't insert the event_id into my notification table in the database. i don't know why my $this->db->insert_id() in $data7. the $data5 and $data6 is working

```
       public function create_event_scholar()
         {
            $now = date('Y-m-d');
            $start=$_POST['start_date'];
            $end=$_POST['end_date'];
            if(($start==$now)||$end==$now){
              $event_status= "Ongoing";
               
                 
                  }
                  else if(($start < $now)&&($end>$now)){
                    $event_status= "Ongoing";
                  }
                  else if(($start<$now)&&($end<$now)){
                    $event_status= "Done";
                    

                  }
                  else {
                    $event_status= "Upcoming";
                  }


            $data = array
             (
              'event_id'     =>      '',
             'event_title'   =>      $this->input->post('event_title',true),
             'event_desc'    =>      $this->input->post('event_desc',true),
             'start_date'    =>      $this->input->post("start_date",true),
             'end_date'      =>      $this->input->post("end_date",true),
             /*'event_status'   =>      $event_status,*/
            'event_sponsor' =>      $this->input->post('event_sponsor',true),
            'Semester'      =>      $this->input->post("Semester",true),
           'school_year'   =>      $this->input->post('school_year',true),
           'event_for'     =>      'Scholar',
           'start_time' =>      $this->input->post('start_time',true),
           'venue'          =>      $this->input->post('venue',true),
           'end_time'       =>      $this->input->post('end_time',true),
          'user_id'     =>      $this->input->post('user_id',true),
          'color '      =>      $this->input->post('color',true)
          );

          $sql1=    $this->db->insert('event',$data);


             $earlier = new DateTime($_POST['start_date']);
              $later = new DateTime($_POST['end_date']);

              $diff = $later->diff($earlier)->format("%a");

                $data = array(
                'security_id'     => "",  
                'event_id'        =>$this->db->insert_id(),
                'scholarship'     =>$this->input->post('scholarship',true),
                'max_attendees'   =>$this->input->post('Participants',true),
                'pre_reg'         =>$this->input->post('pre',true),
                'total_attendance'=>$diff,
                'event_duration'  =>$this->input->post('event_duration',true),
                
                );

        $sql2=$this->db->insert('event_security',$data,'event_id'); 
        
            $data3=array(
        'assign_id'  => '',
        'user_id'   =>$this->input->post('user_id',true),
        'event_id'  =>$this->db->insert_id()
        );
        $sql3=  $this->db->insert('tbl_staff_events',$data3);



         $data5 = array(
        'notification_id'   =>'',
        'subject'           =>$this->input->post('event_title',true),
        'body'              =>"There is an event", 
        'event_id'          =>$this->db->insert_id()


      );

       $this->db->insert('notification',$data5);

        $subject=$this->input->post('scholarship',true);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_scholar');
        $this->db->where('scholarship_id',$subject);
        $get= $this->db->get()->result_array();
        foreach ($get as $value) {
        $data6=array(
        'participants_id'   => '',
        'event_id'          =>$this->db->insert_id(),
         'user_id'          =>$value['user_id']
        );
        $this->db->insert('participants',$data6);
        }

        $data7= array(
       'sent_id'                =>'',
       'read'                   =>'0',
       'recieve'                =>'0',
       'notification_id'        =>$this->db->insert_id(),
       'participants_id'        =>$this->db->insert_id()
        );

        $this->db->insert('sent_notification',$data7);

        if($sql1===true && $sql2===true && $sql3 === true) 
        {
         return true;
         }
        else
        {
        return false;
        }   

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help you,

```
$sql1=    $this->db->insert('event',$data);

$event_id = $this->db->insert_id();

$this->db->insert('notification',$data5);

$notification_id = $this->db->insert_id();

$this->db->insert('participants',$data6);

$participants_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

`$this->db->insert_id();` returns the last executed query id